# Python pandas dataframe modify columns

Tags: python, pandas, windows, dataframe

I have this type of dataframe with two main columns, each column contains two sub-columns divided by commas. This dataframe comes from an online json. I would need 4 columns with the headings bid price, bid, ask price, and ask. Can you advise me how to write the code?
I get an empty dataframe, I don't understand why. here an image of what i get: https://ibb.co/bvfPkXg

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?limit=20&symbol=BTCUSDT")
df = pd.read_json(r.text)
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
data
dp = data.drop('lastUpdateId', axis=1)

# split the text on the comma
dp['bids'] = dp['bids'].str.split(',')
dp['asks'] = dp['asks'].str.split(',')

# store in new the new columns
dp['bid price'] = dp['bids'][0]
dp['bid vol'] = dp['bids'][1]
dp['ask price'] = dp['asks'][0]
dp['ask vol'] = dp['asks'][1]

#show results
dp = dp.iloc[:,2:]
dp
```

Comment: Can you give an example row from the json data please?

Comment: This is an image of the dataframe I have: https://ibb.co/QH1nsw1

Answer (score 0):

## Demo DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['bid price1, bid1', 'bid price2, bid2', 'bid price3, bid3'],

                   'column2': ['ask price1, ask1', 'ask price2, ask2', 'ask price3, ask3']})

​
            column1           column2
0  bid price1, bid1  ask price1, ask1
1  bid price2, bid2  ask price2, ask2
2  bid price3, bid3  ask price3, ask3
```

## Split the text

```
# split the text on the comma

df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.split(',')
df['column2'] = df['column2'].str.split(',')

               column1              column2
0  [bid price1,  bid1]  [ask price1,  ask1]
1  [bid price2,  bid2]  [ask price2,  ask2]
2  [bid price3,  bid3]  [ask price3,  ask3]
```

## Take the First and second value of each list

```
# store in new the new columns

df['bid price'] = df['column1'].str[0]
df['bid'] = df['column1'].str[1]
df['ask price'] = df['column2'].str[0]
df['ask'] = df['column2'].str[1]
```

## Show results

```
df = df.iloc[:,2:]

print(df)

    bid price    bid   ask price    ask
0  bid price1   bid1  ask price1   ask1
1  bid price2   bid2  ask price2   ask2
2  bid price3   bid3  ask price3   ask3
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Your code give me this error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @GianluigiMvutu - well ... the code works. but your description was bad :D In my example, I first split the strings (text into 2 pieces). But in your updated question, they are already digits

Answer (score 0):

Specific result, after updating the qustion:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?limit=20&symbol=BTCUSDT")
df = pd.read_json(r.text)
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
dp = data.drop('lastUpdateId', axis=1)

# store in data into the new columns
dp['bid price'] = dp['bids'].str[0].astype(float)
dp['bid vol'] = dp['bids'].str[1].astype(float)
dp['ask price'] = dp['asks'].str[0].astype(float)
dp['ask vol'] = dp['asks'].str[1].astype(float)

dp = dp.drop(['bids', 'asks'], axis=1)


    bid price   bid vol     ask price   ask vol
0   38933.43    2.51460     38933.44    5.94267
1   38933.41    0.12812     38933.46    0.01073
2   38933.36    0.00200     38934.09    0.00965
3   38932.41    0.00037     38934.34    1.14567
4   38932.24    0.00440     38934.42    0.06000
5   38932.12    0.00266     38934.76    0.17284
6   38931.73    0.00596     38935.36    0.34796
7   38931.70    0.00166     38935.42    0.12840
8   38931.69    0.12843     38935.87    0.38523
9   38931.48    0.04000     38936.17    0.00027
```